# Header location - This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I am trying to redirect to a form page however I got the following message

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I have been able to figure that

```
header('Location: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/send');
```

is causing the error I have tried a number of different things including adding exit underneath the final line of code but it still seems to be looping.

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Send
    */
?>

<?php
    session_start();
    require_once(get_template_directory().'/vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');


    $errors = [];

    if(isset($_POST['customername'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'])) {
        $fields = [
            'name' => $_POST['customername'],
            'email' => $_POST['email'],
            'message' => $_POST['message']
        ];

        foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
            if (empty($data)) {
                  $errors[] = 'The ' . $field . ' field is required';
            }
        }
    } else {

        $errors[] = 'Something went wrong.';
    }

    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/wordpress/send');
    exit();
```

Comment: You have to move the `header()` function in a conditional block. As it's written it's always executed.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example please?

Comment: What happen if the form does not return an error? The redirect should go there but it looks like your code perform nothing if there is no error.

Comment: On what page this php code exists `http://localhost:8888/......` ?

Comment: Move header in conditional block  in your if check empty $errors after  `foreach { ...} if(count($errors)==0){ header(...) }`

Comment: I am following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtWD_ZH9lnE at 9.32 the code is pretty much the same yet he does not have the error I do the only difference is I am going mine within a WordPress theme